# How do you force an end turn in Civilization VI running on iOS?

Tags: ios, civilization-6

If I have a lot of units that I have awake, but waiting for war, I have to go to each unit and tell it to skip its turn. I remember when I played CIV on the PC and MAC I.

Comment: At least on PC, you could fortify any units you don't need to move and all turns after that should automatically skip those units.

Comment: I’ve been trying to get the answer for this for ages - with no luck.  Can I presume you are still looking?

Comment: I haven't been looking but have you tried my suggestion? You'll have to spend a turn fortifying your units, but after that it should hopefully achieve what you are after.

Comment: On the desktop, shift+enter foce-ends the turn. This has been the case probably ever since civII or so. I have no idea if there's an equivalent on a mobile device though.